# How do I target a namespaced XML attribute in XSL using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xslt, xpath, nokogiri

Say I have XML that partly looks like this:

```
... lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <ext-link href="http://www.consectetur.org/">consectetur</ext-link> adipiscing elit ...
```

I can quite easily target that URL in XSD with

```
<xsl:template match="ext-link">
    <a href="{@href}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

But when my XML looks like this, I'm at a loss:

```
... lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <ext-link xlink:href="http://www.consectetur.org/">consectetur</ext-link> adipiscing elit ...
```

This doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="ext-link">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Neither does `@xlink` or `@href`. What essential XML/XSL knowledge am I missing here?

**Update**

Since I'm using Nokogiri for parsing, what I'm probably missing is how to tell it to associate namespaces - I'm not sure where to do this. I'm pulling in XML and XSL like so

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('/some/xml/path'))
xslt = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('/some/xsl/path'))

result = xslt.transform(doc)
```

Using this, all `{@xlink}`, `{@href}` or `{@xlink:href}` in my XML render nothing in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *source* document isn’t using namespaces (perhaps the declaration has been removed somehow) then you need to select the attribute with no namespace and the “local” name `xlink:href`. This is a little tricky with XPath because it will interpret the `:` as separating the namespace, but you can do it like this using the [`name()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name):

```xml
<xsl:template match="ext-link">
  <a href="{@*[name() = 'xlink:href']}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The source XML document will have the namespace declared somewhere higher up the tree, assuming this is the standard XLink mechanism that will be

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

In order to refer to an attribute with the local name `href` and the namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink` you need to bind the same namespace URI to a prefix *in the stylesheet* and then use this prefix in your XPath expressions.  E.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="..."
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <xsl:template match="ext-link">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case `xlink` is the conventional prefix for that URI, but in general the prefix doesn't have to be the same one as the source document used, all that matters is that it maps to the right URI.  This would work just as well:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="..."
                xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <xsl:template match="ext-link">
    <a href="{@xl:href}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ian. Namespace declaration in my XSL looks to be correct, however `{@xlink:href}` still returns nothing. I'm guessing Nokogiri, which I am using to parse both XML and XSL, might need some attributes. I'll update my question.